# .Ubuntu 14.04 IP6 Timed Out

Tags: 14.04

i have Ubuntu 14.04 When i try to connect to a Router it connecting properly but there is no internet access. I recently read the syslog and found this lines...Please tell me what does it mean "IP6 Timed out" and how to fix it.

syslog:

```
Apr 23 19:31:30 IQ-GST-BOX NetworkManager[1003]: <info> (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Apr 23 19:31:30 IQ-GST-BOX NetworkManager[1003]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Apr 23 19:31:30 IQ-GST-BOX NetworkManager[1003]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Apr 23 19:31:30 IQ-GST-BOX NetworkManager[1003]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
```

And this `ifconfig -a` output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:b6:fd:38:4d:a5  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:662504 (662.5 KB)  TX bytes:662504 (662.5 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 64:27:37:e6:68:d9  
          inet addr:192.168.0.103  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6627:37ff:fee6:68d9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:570615 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:522545
          TX packets:463960 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:729850876 (729.8 MB)  TX bytes:42401358 (42.4 MB)
          Interrupt:17
```

`nm-tool` output:

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        24:B6:FD:38:4D:A5

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off


- Device: wlan0  [IQ-GST-BOX] ----------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            wl
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        64:27:37:E6:68:D9

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           1 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    *IQ-GST-BOX: Infra, 10:FE:ED:C8:AE:5A, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 32 WPA WPA2
    IQ-GST-BOX: Infra, 00:27:22:4C:0E:06, Freq 2422 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 24

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.103
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1
```

Thanks...

Comment: Ubuntu is trying to get an IPv6 address but doesn't get one. This usually isn't a problem as you probably do get an IPv4 address (IPv6 is still not available everywhere). Could you please update your question with the output of `ifconfig -a` and `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Please put output in code blocks to improve readability next time. Could you please also post the result of `ping 8.8.8.8` and `ping google.com`?

Comment: Ok i'll do it next time... i ping google.com and 8.8.8.8 there is no problem at all and i get responses... i encounter this issue when i try to connect to another router

Comment: Okay, what do you mean exactly by connecting to another router? You want to access its web interface? What's the IP address of the other router and how is it connected to your network?

Comment: Now i connected to a Router and there is no any issues with it but yesterday i tried to connect to my friend's Router but i couldn't access the web interface

Comment: Okay, at least it's working now then. I guess your problem is solved now?

Comment: Okay,thank you. But i still wanna solve this issue

Comment: I think your question about IP6 addrconf timeouts has been answered. Please create a new question if you have questions about anything else.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, IPv6 timeout simply means that Network Manager looked for but was not offered an IPv6 address. That's not alarming or uncommon, as relatively few Internet Service Providers are set up for IPv6 and, if they are, relatively few consumer-grade routers behind the ISP pass IPv6. As long as you get an IPv4 address, possibly something like 192.168.x.y, you should be fine.

If you'd like to troubleshoot why you have an address but no internet access, edit your post to add the result of:

```
nm-tool
```